# Apartment/other, from July to October. Best option?

Tags: canada, rent, real-estate-leasing

I will be leaving my current apartment on the 1st of July (in Quebec leases mainly end on this date). Also, I will be travelling for about 4 months, starting from around November. Having to pay for 6 months for an apartment for nothing would be a waste of money, and trying to not have a sublet renter cancel on me, while on the other side of the world, would be complicated as well.

From my searching so far, one of my options would be to rent a monthly apartment (and Airbnb type apartments), however, in the city where I live in, bedbugs are quite common and I would rather avoid this. I don't know if there would also be sublets/subleases that start in July (since yearly leases end on this date). Is this correct? Renting a room could also be an option, but I really like my own space, kitchen, etc.

So, what would be good options to have an apartment from the start of July (moving day/yearly leases end in Quebec) to the end of October?

Comment: For reference, are you in Quebec? I ask because I am only familiar with Quebec having the "Canada Day = Moving Day" tradition. It may impact some of the answers more specific to that region, where the July leases are more standard. Also - if you are concerned about bedbugs, I recommend you check BedBugRegistry.com [no affiliation]. It allows users to lodge complaints against locations they stay at where bed bugs are present. Not foolproof, but may help put your mind at ease (or convince you to move).

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Yes, I'm in Québec. Thanks for the response and suggestions!

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon why not just do Airbnb / vrbo and buy a new mattress / take your own?

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon - maybe it's different with the varieties in Canada, but my relatives in KY recently had a bedbug problem, and chemical + starve approach has worked quite successfully